# How to disable security feature for Unit testing in Spring Webflux

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-webflux

My `Unit tests are passed` already. After I added the Security with `JWT token`, the passed unit tests are `failed` cos of Security features. I would like to `disable security features` for unit tests. I don't want to `rewrite` all the test cases.

Can I `disable the security features` for unit tests?

I used `Spring Boot 2.1.1`, `Webflux`, and `RouterFunction` instead of controller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is best solution or not. I generated `unexpired token` and used it in My unit test cases.